# How to send message to JMS server from one machine and receive that from another machine in JBoss 7

Tags: java, jms, jboss7.x

I am trying to send message(TextMessage) to `JMS server` from my laptop, then I am trying to receive that message from another laptop. I am using `JBoss AS 7.1`. My both laptops are connected in same network.

When I am doing  that I am getting exception. I searched for this in google and some is saying that in `JBoss 7.1 JNDI` will not get connections from remote IP's and they are saying that we have to use `HornetQ`.

Can any one please help in this issue.

Comment: Are you able to ping the other laptop ? What is the exception stracktrace ? Are you able to use similar client code in the server and does it work in one machine ?

Comment: Yes, Ican ping the laptop. As well as I can send message and receive with in laptop. But when I want to send from one laptop and receive from other its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have two queues, one on each machine. They only have the same name, but are not connected in any way. You could make the sender machine use the remote queue directly, but it's advisable to use (like you have) two queues instead, one on each node, and then configure a **bridge** to move the messages from one to the other. In this way, sending as well as receiving messages will work within your local transactions, which is what you'll normally want.

In order to configure the bridge, HornetQ offers two options: A generic JMS bridge, and a core bridge. The former is generic, as it can bridge between JMS queues of *any* JMS provider. But the HornetQ docs recommend core bridges when using HornetQ on both sides, as they are faster and more robust.

The [JBoss docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Messaging+configuration) (the section "JMS Bridge"), describes the setup for a JMS-Bridge using the CLI. The [HornetQ docs for core bridges](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/core-bridges.html) describes the stand alone setup (outside of the JBoss server); converting that to CLI, you'll get (replace the parts in curly brackets with your values):

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/bridge={bridge-name}:add(queue-name="{queue-name}", forwarding-address="{remote-hostname}", static-connectors=["http-acceptor"])
```

To see a brief description of all parameters, use this command:

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/bridge=x:read-resource-description
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this, because i am new to JBoss 7.

Comment: @user3396452: I'm not sure about what to elaborate on. Maybe you don't you know how to use the CLI?

Comment: Can you please explain me all the spe steps instead of telling technically